# What is the best way to setup multiple many-to-many relationships in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, associations

I am fairly new to RoR - so please be gentle :)

i am trying to setup an environment that has two many to many relationships.

What I am thinking is:

```
class A
  has_many :c
  has_many :d
  has_many :b, :through=>c
  has_many :b, :through=>d
end

class B
  has_many :c
  has_many :d
  has_many :a, :through=>c
  has_many :a, :through=>d
end

class C
  belongs_top :a
  belongs_to :b
end

class D
  belongs_top :a
  belongs_to :b
end
```

From all this I have read multiple :through associations to the one attribute in the one class will not work.  And the whole purpose of this setup is so I can easily call data with reference to both c and d - ie @a.c and @a.d, as well as @b.c and @b.d.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Damo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple has_many :through associations, but you just need to give them different names:

```
class A
  has_many :c
  has_many :d
  has_many :cb, :through=>c, :class_name => "B"
  has_many :db, :through=>d, :class_name => "B
end
```